# AutoSuggestBox Suggestion Results Get Out of The Suggestion List

Tags: c#, uwp

I already made an image describing the problem. [image: Results find its way out of the suggestion box]

I already set the MaxSuggestionListHeight and it didn't help at all.

the ItemSource is from a SQLite Database. Does this play a role?

Comment: Could you provide a sample with less code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: please try to set MinHeight also and see if the issue is still there or not